# VSCode: PHP syntax error on multiple return types

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, type-hinting

[syntax errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuhug.png)

Its ok where we have one return type, and syntax error when two

What should i install to have correctly supported syntax for this, There is no mistake in code and php-interpreter accepts this fully correct use

Comment: I think you should write something like `intval($your_var)` as you want to make sure it's an integer on return then it will not give any error.

Comment: Stack Overflow pages are not marked as resolved by appending SOLVED to the question title.  You must never provide textual question details as screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

You need PHP 8.0 or newer to support [union types](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/union-types)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some plugin configuration error.

What vscode plugin do you use?

I recommend to install [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DEVSENSE.phptools-vscode) one - it has support of php >8.0 features, which will be useful and probably solve your problem.

Comment: i uninstalled intelephense and "php extension pack" plugins, and leaved only php tools u recommened, which was already installed. but have the same result (((

Comment: "{" expected it writes

Comment: In status bar, right side, is there php version displayed? If not, right click on status bar and select "PHP Tools". "8.0" or "8.1" must be there.

Comment: Tony Sol
 i uninstalled php tools and then reinstalled it, Now it works + yeah, there is php version in place u mentioned, thanks a lot!!! Now it awesome))

Comment: Well, that's strange :c
Try with this config:
```
    "php.suggest.basic": false,
    "php.validate.run": "onType",
    "php.validate.enable": false,
    "php.linkedEditing.variables": true,
    "php.executablePath": "path",
```
where your actual php executable path will be instead of "path"

Comment: php.executablePath": "path", ``` where your actual php executable path will be instead of "path"

====

with php.exe or directory??, at the time there is 
"php.executablePath": "C:/xampp/php/php.exe",

Answer (score 0):

Removed PHP Tools, removed php intelisense, reload and after installed only php intellisense

Now it works))

Comment: You may accept your own answer to mark this page as resolved.